# attach a variable to each instance of BX slider generated in an .each() statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, each, bxslider

I have some jQuery that creates a slideshow using BX slider for an unknown number of galleries. The markup is output by a PHP CMS and so we can't be confident of the number of galleries we will need on a page.

```
$(function () {

    // Use a class rather than an ID
    var $slider = $('.gallery');

    // For each result
    $slider.each(function (index, element) {

        // If there is more than 1 image
        if ($(element).find('img').length > 1) {

            // Initialise a slider using the current index value
            $slider.eq(index).bxSlider({
                auto: false,
                pager: false,
                duration: 500
            });

        }

    });

});
```

In order to use the public functions I need to define each instance of the BX slider as a variable.

So `var slider = $('#gallery').bxSlider();` would be the norm. How can I generate these variables on the fly within this each statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$(function () {

    var bxSliderInstances = {};

    // Use a class rather than an ID
    var $slider = $('.gallery');

    // For each result
    $slider.each(function (index, element) {

        // If there is more than 1 image
        if ($(element).find('img').length > 1) {

            // Initialise a slider using the current index value
            bxSliderInstances["slider" + index] = $slider.eq(index).bxSlider({
                auto: false,
                pager: false,
                duration: 500
            });

        }

    });

});
```

`bxSliderInstances` will contain all the slider instances as an associative array which you can use as per your need.

E.g `bxSliderInstances.slider1` or `` `bxSliderInstances["slider1"] `` will give you the first `bxSlider` instance.

Comment: That looks perfect. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Would it be possible to use them all at once?
Would `bxSliderInstances.goToNextSlide()` work for example?